# Escape from Windows 10 S mode a second time

Tags: windows-10, windows-10s

I'm working on a laptop that came in Windows 10 S mode (don't ask). The laptop has already switched out of S mode via the Windows Store app. This was some time ago. Later, I ran a BIOS update for the laptop. After updating the BIOS, the laptop has reverted to S mode (which is not supposed to be possible!)

[image: Windows 10 Pro in S mode via Activation]
[image: Windows 10 Pro in S mode via winver]

Worse, trying to leave S mode again the normal way — via the Windows Store — no longer works. I can find the "Switch out of S Mode" app, but when I click the "Get" button I just get an unhelpful error message: "Try again later. Something happened on our end".

[image: Try again later. Something happened on our end]

I also looked in the Event Viewer, but I don't see any events corresponding to this message.

How can I leave S mode, when the supported option is not working? Surely there must be a manual way to perform the same steps as the Windows Store app. Alternatively, can I revert whatever the app had done before that is confusing the ability to run the process again?

---

More digging, I found this message in the Event Viewer:

```js
{
    "code":"Forbidden",
    "data":[],
    "details":[],
    "innererror": {
        "code":"UserAlreadyOwnsContent",
        "data":["BF712690PMLF"],
        "details":[],
        "message":"Purchase policy restricts user msahw:999999999999999 from purchasing certain content multiple times",
        "source":"PurchaseFD"
    },
    "message":"Access to the requested resource is forbidden.",
    "source":"PurchaseFD"
}
```

So it seems this is blocked by policy in the store, and there's probably no way to revert the purchase. I'll need to find a way to manually do the same thing the app was doing.

Comment: *> After updating the BIOS, the laptop has reverted to S mode* -- what's telling you that? Do you perhaps just have it set to [only allow installations from Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F4wM.png), which might feel like S mode without actually being so?

Comment: Running `winver`. I'll add a screen shot.

Comment: Also, the Activation page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:

> https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Bios-update-caused-switch-back-to-S-mode/td-p/7591947

In short:

Open the "Run" prompt by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
Then type `WSReset.exe` into the box and click OK or press Enter.

[image: WSReset.exe]

After waiting a few minutes for the program to run, things were okay again. I didn't even need to re-install the app. It was enough to load the Activation page in Settings, and the check there fixed me. (I may also have needed to sign into the store.)

Answer (score -1):

To get out of S Mode without an app or using one at all or any MS Account, you can disable secure boot in the BIOS.

Just did that on a laptop I got a couple days ago. I didn't want any Microsoft Account associated with the laptop at all.